# how to split data from text file and create separate columns at a specific position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file

it is a sample data

```
ao112   qwertyuiopasdfgh
ao12234 isbcbcobcwocbwowd
ao12    lscnldcnoodqhiod
```

I want to create a data frame using .txt file where the data frame needs to create separate columns in this example(2 columns) using this info
col name   | position
code       |1-7
blank      |8
description|9- to end
I need to create a dataframe columns by seprating from a specific position in the example case that is at blank position

**tried using this code but unable to find what parameter should I use in sep**

`data=pd.read_csv('filepath',sep='  ',name=['code','description'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

You can infer the format using `colspecs='infer'` or provide a full list of the ranges.

> colspecslist of tuple (int, int) or ‘infer’. optional
>
> A list of tuples giving the extents of the fixed-width fields of each line as half-open intervals (i.e., [from, to[ ). String value
> ‘infer’ can be used to instruct the parser to try detecting the column
> specifications from the first 100 rows of the data which are not being
> skipped via skiprows (default=’infer’).

```
(pd.read_fwf('filepath', colspecs='infer', header=None)
   .set_axis(['code','description'], axis=1)
)
```

Alternatively, use a regex separator with `pandas.read_csv` (if you have one or more spaces as delimiter):

```
pd.read_csv('filepath', sep='\s+', names=['code','description'])
```

output:

```
      code        description
0    ao112   qwertyuiopasdfgh
1  ao12234  isbcbcobcwocbwowd
2     ao12   lscnldcnoodqhiod
```

Comment: well, what should i do for this type of scenario? 
`code     description
ao1233 kdpncwdc qsndwoiend qsonqondo `
here the sep='\s+' will not work an what's the alternative in read_csv

Comment: Why not? Should you have 2 or 3 columns in this case?

Comment: only 2 columns but if i use the above read_csv method it will create (from my example) 4 columns

Comment: In this case I guess `read_fwf` is required

Comment: with the help of this method read_fwf my required output is been acquired but if I use read_csv i couldn't get the same output as read_fwf.
i want to know if it is possible or not
only need 2 columns but if i use the above read_csv method it will create (from my example) 4 columns

Comment: If you had at least 2 spaces between 2 columns, you could use `read_csv` with `\s\s+` as separator, but this doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: so it is not possible in read_csv should go with read_fwf